# Алгоритм Шенкса-Тонелли

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Есть две последовательности чисел:

*x*, *x* + 1, *x* + 2, ...

и

*x*<sup>2</sup>(mod *n*), (*x* + 1)<sup>2</sup>(mod *n*), (*x* + 2)<sup>2</sup>(mod *n*), ... где *n* — любое: *n* ⩽ *x*<sup>2</sup>.

Необходимо найти первый элемент из второй последовательности, который делится на простое *p*.

Простым перебором от начала последовательности это делать долго при большой последовательности и больших *p*.

На сколько я понял, тут нужно использовать алгоритм Шенкса-Тонелли.
Правда, я не понял, как его тут применить.

**Собственно вопрос:** как применить к данной задаче данный алгоритм?

Или, если вы знаете способ решить задачу еще быстрее — как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, не так много где этот вопрос расписан, особенно, в русскоязычной литературе.

Я бы тоже не стал описывать ответ если бы не одно но: данный вопрос актуален при реализации ***алгоритма квадратичного решета*** на этапе просеивания.  Решение данного сравнения позволит найти элементы, делящиеся на числа из факторной базы *без перебора*, что значительно ускорит процесс просеивания при больших простых из факторной базы.

Собственно, ответ на мой вопрос:

**Сперва теория:**

Рассмотрим конечное поле *GF<sub>p</sub>* (*p* > 2), и элемент *a*, являющийся
квадратичным вычетом по модулю *p*. Требуется найти x такое, что *x*<sup>2</sup> ≡ *n* (mod *p*).

Представим число *p* − 1 в виде *p* − 1 = 2<sup>*r*</sup>*s*, где *s* – нечетно. Заметим, что поскольку *p* − 1 – четно, то *r* ⩾ 1.

Пусть *z* – квадратичный невычет по модулю *p*. Вычислим *y* ≡ *z*<sup>*s*</sup> (mod *p*). Поскольку порядок любого элемента является делителем числа 2<sup>*r*</sup>*s*, то порядок *y* является делителем 2<sup>*r*</sup>, откуда *y*<sup>2<sup>*r*</sup></sup> ≡ 1 (mod *p*). Можно также показать, что *y*<sup>2<sup>*r*−1</sup></sup> ≡ −1 (mod *p*), т.е. порядок элемента *y* равен в точности 2<sup>*r*</sup>.

Вычислим далее элементы:

λ<sub>0</sub> ≡ *a*<sup>*s*</sup> (mod *p*)
ω<sub>0</sub> ≡ *a*<sup>(*s*+1)/2</sup> (mod *p*)

Заметим, что ω<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> ≡ *a*λ<sub>0</sub> (mod *p*) и *x*<sup>2</sup> ≡ *a* (mod *p*) ⟹ *x*<sup>2*s*</sup> ≡ *a*<sup>*s*</sup> ≡ λ<sub>0</sub> (mod *p*).

Поскольку порядок элемента *x*<sup>*s*</sup> является делителем 2<sup>*r*</sup>, то порядок
λ<sub>0</sub> является делителем 2<sup>*r*−1</sup>.

*Идея метода Шенкса–Тоннелли* состоит в построении последовательности пар чисел (ω<sub>*i*</sub>, λ<sub>*i*</sub>), удовлетворяющих условию:

ω<sub>*i*</sub><sup>2</sup> ≡ *a*λ<sub>*i*</sub> (mod *p*)
(*i* = 1, 2, 3, ...)

причем порядок λ<sub>*i*+1</sub> является собственным делителем порядка λ<sub>*i*</sub>, до тех пор, пока порядок очередного λ<sub>*i*</sub> не окажется равным 0. Тогда для найденного *i* выполнятся условия
λ<sub>*i*</sub> = 1 и ω<sub>*i*</sub><sup>2</sup> ≡ *a* (mod *p*)
откуда *x* = ω<sub>*i*</sub> является искомым корнем.

Поскольку исходные значения (λ<sub>0</sub>, ω<sub>0</sub>) уже определены, то осталось просто описать формулы для вычисления значений (λ<sub>*i*+1</sub>, ω<sub>*i*+1</sub>):

λ<sub>*i*+1</sub> ≡ λ<sub>*i*</sub> · *a* · *y*<sup>2<sup>*r*−*m*</sup></sup>(mod *p*)
ω<sub>*i*+1</sub> ≡ ω<sub>*i*+1</sub> · *y*<sup>2<sup>*r*−*m*−1</sup></sup>(mod *p*)

где *m* - порядок элемента λ<sub>*i*</sub>.
Так же, корнями будут все числа, кратные *p*.

**Реализация** же алгоритма крайне проста:

```
int Shenks_Tonelli(int p,long long n){
    n=n%p;
    int s=p-1,r=0;
    //получаем разложение p-1  
    while(s%2==0){
        s/=2;
        r++;
    }
    //начальные значения: λ и ω  
    int l = PowMod(n,s,p);
    int w = PowMod(n,(s+1)/2,p);
    //находим порядок λ
    int mod=l,m=0;
    while(mod!=1){
        mod=MulMod(mod,mod,p);
        m++;
    }
    //находим квадратичный невычет
    int z = quadratic nonresidue(p);
    //находим коэф-ты, на которые будем умножать
    int yd_l=PowMod(PowMod(z,s,p),pow(2,r-m),p);
    int yd_w=PowMod(PowMod(z,s,p),pow(2,r-m-1),p);
    //находим корень    
    while(l!=1){
        l=MulMod(l,yd_l,p);
        w=MulMod(w,yd_w,p);
    }
    return w;
}
```

Правда, этап просеивания можно еще ускорить, если находить корни сравнения *x*<sup>2</sup> ≡ *n* (mod *p*<sup>β</sup>), и делить числа, отстоящие от них на *p*<sup>β</sup>, постепенно понижая β. Корни такого сравнения находятся по индукции. Подробнее об этом [здесь](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/20659/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0).